# How to run N requests and if any succeed to use its result

Tags: angular, rxjs, nestjs

I do have a number of urls. Some of these urls may fail, some may not.

I want to run requests `one by one` or `all at the same time` to figure-out which one will succeed to proceed with its result up on the chain.

Using `forkJoin` might be a potential solution that will run all requests simultaneously, but if any requests will fail the forkJoin is failing.

```
private getData() {
    const url1 = myUrl1;
    const url2 = myUrl2;

    forkJoin([this.http.get<Data>(url1), this.http.get<Data>(url2)]).pipe(
      
    )

    return successfulReultHere
  }
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what the question here is but `forkJoin` only fails if you don't catch the error.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest this solution

```
private getData() {
    const url1 = myUrl1;
    const url2 = myUrl2;

    return merge([
       this.http.get<Data>(url1).pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY)),
       this.http.get<Data>(url2).pipe(catchError(() => EMPTY))
    ]).pipe(
      first()
    )
  }
```

here we merge both of the "sources" and the first result that succeds goes straing to output. we also ignore the errors and any other results. also `first()` will make sure that error will be emmited if there is not a single success during http calls

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `forkJoin` with individual `catchError` operators for each of the apis like below -

```
private getData$() {
    const url1 = `myUrl1`;
    const url2 = `myUrl2`;

    return forkJoin([
       this.http.get<Data>(url1).pipe(catchError(e => of('Error in url1'))), 
       this.http.get<Data>(url2).pipe(catchError(e => of('Error in url2')))
    ]);
  }
```

Even if one of the apis fail, the error will be caught in the respective catchError which will return a new observable, so that it won't impact other API observable results.